# How to pass parameters to widgets in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am opening a modal dialog in Flutter and wish to pass in a single parameter (postId) to the modal for further processing. But this is generating an error as shown.

```
class SharingDialog extends StatefulWidget {
 @override

 final String postId;  // <--- generates the error, "Field doesn't override an inherited getter or setter"
 SharingDialog({
   String postId
 }): this.postId = postId;

 SharingDialogState createState() => new SharingDialogState(postId);
}

class SharingDialogState extends State<SharingDialog> {

 SharingDialogState(this.postId);
 final String postId;

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return new Scaffold(
     appBar: 
       child: AppBar(           
         title: const Text('Share this Post'),
      actions: [
        new FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print("Sharing Post ID: " + this.postId);
          },
          child: new Text('SHARE)
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  body: new Text("SHARING SCREEN"),
);
}
```

And then there is a click to open the modal using the following code which generates the accompanying error:

Code:

```
return new SharingDialog(postId);
```

Error: `Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 1 found.`

How do you pass parameter(s) if not this way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First:

Remove override keyword above postId

```
  @override <-- this one
  final String postId;
```

Second:

Because you are using named parameter , send the param like this way:

```
   return new SharingDialog(postId: postId);
```

If you want more information about Optional named parameters, check this link:

https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#optional-parameters